# Hypothesis strategy generating inf when specifically asked not to

Tags: python, numpy, python-hypothesis

```
from functools import partial
import hypothesis as h
import hypothesis.strategies as hs
import hypothesis.extra.numpy as hnp
import numpy as np


floats_notnull = partial(hs.floats, allow_nan=False, allow_infinity=False)
complex_notnull = partial(hs.complex_numbers, allow_nan=False, allow_infinity=False)

data_strategy_real = hnp.arrays(
    np.float64,
    hs.tuples(hs.integers(min_value=2, max_value=50),
              hs.integers(min_value=2, max_value=5)),
    floats_notnull()
)

data_strategy_complex = hnp.arrays(
    np.complex64,
    hs.tuples(hs.integers(min_value=2, max_value=50), hs.just(1)),
    complex_notnull()
)

data_strategy = hs.one_of(data_strategy_real, data_strategy_complex)
```

If you run `data_strategy.example()` a couple times, you'll notice that some of the values in the result have infinite real or imaginary parts. My intention here was to specifically disallow infinite or NaN parts.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**: if I use

```
data_strategy = hs.lists(complex_notnull, min_size=2, max_size=50)
```

and convert that to an array inside my test, the problem appears to go away. Are the complex numbers overflowing? I'm not getting the usual deprecation warning about overflow from Hypothesis.

And if I use

```
data_strategy = data_strategy_real
```

no `inf`s appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The complex64 type is too small and it's overflowing. Somehow Hypothesis is failing to catch this.

Yep, the root cause of this problem is that you're generating *64-bit* finite floats, then casting them to 32-bit (because `complex64` is a pair of 32-bit floats).  You can fix that with the `width=32` argument to `floats()`:

```
floats_notnull_32 = partial(hs.floats, allow_nan=False, allow_infinity=False, width=32)
```

And you're not getting the usual overflow check because [it's only implemented for floats and integers](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/blob/b4a064f0d922c04a53cc8a8b498260875110c2a4/hypothesis-python/src/hypothesis/extra/numpy.py#L135-L148) at the moment.  I've opened (edit: and fixed) [issue #1591](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/1591) to check complex and string types too.

Answer (score 1):

The `complex64` type is too small and it's overflowing. Somehow Hypothesis is failing to catch this.

Switching to `complex128` fixed the problem for now.